# New Gmail contacts in Android

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, android

Since last month Gmail launched a new Contacts interface.

[image]

The best thing is that somehow my contacts list has been cleaned, I don't have 4.000+ contacts anymore (gmail creates a contact with every new email adresss, I know I can disable this, I don't want to), I have a list of aprox. 300 that are my real contacts.

The thing is that in my phone is still see the 4.000+ contacts list, I already synced the list but is still the same. Any ideas???

Comment: Questions about Android corresponds to [android.se].

Comment: @Rubén I think this is okay here, since it deals with the overall system and not just the Android interface.

Answer (score 3):

The new Google Contacts features at this time are only for the web interface. Regarding the "contacts has been cleaned", the new Google Contacts doesn't display the contacts that only have an email address, like those that are added automatically. If you return to the old version, there you will find all your contacts.

As fair as I know, Android devices will sync all the contacts in the gmail account, but you could choose with group or groups will be displayed.

**References**
[The new Google Contacts: Bringing everyone together - Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2015/03/the-new-google-contacts-bringing.html)
[Is there any way to sync a subset of my Google Contacts to my Android? [duplicate] -  Android Enthusiast - StackExchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24646/is-there-any-way-to-sync-a-subset-of-my-google-contacts-to-my-android)

Comment: I guess I'll have to deal with all the contacts... thanks anyway!